# Find a value that corresponds to another

Tags: excel-formula

I have set up a table that includes values for products used in several industries. I have used the COUNT function so I can find the industry that uses the greatest number of products.

Now I want to identify the cell in the column of COUNT results that has the maximum value and return the name of the corresponding industry from the left hand column.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAX` to identify the highest count amongst the counts and then use that to `VLOOKUP` the matching industry.  For `VLOOKUP` to work the count must be left of the industry.  If you can't arrange this, you can accomplish the same thing with a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`.

For example, if you have counts in `A1:A6` and industries in `B1:B6`, you can find the industry with the most counts with

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(A1:A6),A1:B6,2,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [=MAX](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/max-HP005209170.aspx0) to find the maximum value, then [=MATCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php) to find which row the maximum value is in and [=INDEX](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_function.php) to find the name of the corresponding industry. Since *left hand column* =VLOOKUP is unlikely to suit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the count value all figured out and you know what sheet that they are located within in your workbook, you can use something similar to the following:
Using the following data:
Col A      Col B
Industry   ProductVal
A          11
B          45
C          22
D          9
E          8
F          12

Assuming that you already have assigned 45, the largest value in column B to a cell, you can substitute the 45 below for that cell.

```
  =INDEX(A2:B7,MATCH(45,B2:B7,0),1)
```

The above excel formula will return the value of B which is the value to the left of the "match value" of 45. A brief explanation is you define the index as the entire set of columns that are bounded on the left by the industry and on the right by the value. In the above example that was A and B. The Match then reads, find the value of 45 in the column B from row 2 - row 7 and match the first exact match (that is what the zero is for) and the 1 from the index function indicates that you will return the value that is in the first column (reading left to right) of the INDEX array A2:B7.

You can find an [explanation of index here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-HP005209138.aspx), an [explanation of match here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-HP005209168.aspx)
and a nice explanation of [using them together](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dynamic-searching-using-vlookup-match-and-index-HA001154902.aspx) here.

Best of luck.